# Struct Size, check if 64-bit or 32-bit

Tags: c#

I have an windows application that performs a simple routine to determine whether a USB token is present.  The method has always worked correctly on 32-bit machines however during testing on a 64-bit machine we started to see unexpected results.

I am calling the following method

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    public Int32 cbSize;
    public Guid ClassGuid;
    public Int32 DevInst;
    public UIntPtr Reserved;
};

[DllImport("setupapi.dll")] 
internal static extern Int32 SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, Int32 MemberIndex, ref  SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);
```

The documentation for the [SP_DEVINFO_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552344(VS.85).aspx) structure tells us that the **cbSize** is
the size, in bytes, of the SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure.

If we calculate cbSize for a 32-bit machine it will be 28 and 32 for a 64-bit machine.

I have tested this on both machines by recompiling with different cbSize values, what i want to know is how can i calculate this as runtime?  My application need to run on both architectures.

```
internal static Int32 GetDeviceInfoData(Int32 iMemberIndex)
{
    _deviceInfoData = new Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        cbSize = ?? // 28 When 32-Bit, 32 When 64-Bit,
        ClassGuid = Guid.Empty,
        DevInst = 0,
        Reserved = UIntPtr.Zero
    };

    return Win32DeviceMgmt.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(_deviceInfoSet, iMemberIndex, ref _deviceInfoData);
}
```

Thanks

Rohan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Marshal.SizeOf:

```
_deviceInfoData = new Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
        // etc..
    }
```

Comment: Hans, this solves the problem of how to pass in the actual size, so I'm upvoting.  However, I'm still a bit concerned about packing. No point passing the actual size when it's wrong.

Comment: @Steven - if the packing is wrong then setting cbSize to a constant value is actually a very bad thing to do.  It won't allow the API to detect that you got it wrong and report a good error.  It will just randomly fail since it will read garbage.

Comment: @Hans: That's a good point. It can fail either way, though. If the packing is wrong then the cb will be accurate but the wrong fields will be used. Maybe the right answer is to calculate what you believe the right answer should be, using `IntPtr.Size` and other information, and then compare it to the `Marshal.SizeOf` of the whole. If they don't match, throw an exception. What do you think?

Comment: @Steven: no, if the packing is wrong then cbSize can never be right.  Because Marshal.SizeOf() will *always* return the wrong value.  The only hope you have when the packing is wrong is that it doesn't matter because the outcome is the same, the members can align by accident.  Not that uncommon and something you'll get whacked with when you move to 64-bit code.  The cbSize field in the typical Win32 API call is really rather a good idea, one of the many implementation details about Win32 that Microsoft got ingeniously right.  It is far less typical then it should be.

Comment: For the record, there were a few places where they screwed up.  The LVITEM structure is a good example.  Note the many #ifdefs in that one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer your original comment, didn't get far enough without the knee-jerk reaction.  That approach is flawed because it assumes that the size is known up front.  It isn't twenty years from now.  Do you want to adapt yourself to the user's declaration?  Marshal.SizeOf().  Or do you want to introduce a separate failure mode that completely ignores the efforts of the user to make it compatible?

Comment: @Hans: You're right that packing will disrupt the cbSize. However, in some cases, the struct is just the header of a larger buffer, so the cbSize is not the deciding factor. In other words, it's still possible for the cbSize to be valid while the packing is wrong, though not in this case. The strongest argument you've made is that any attempt to check for the correctness of a cbSize against independent calculations (based on IntPtr.Size) is likely to avoid errors today but only at the cost of preventing the code from automatically working in the future. I concede this.

Comment: Bottom line: We should use `Marshal.SizeOf`, but test the code on the platforms we support, with the expectation that new platforms might break things.

Answer (score 1):

The size of `IntPtr` changes on 32 and 64
Try

```
cbsize = IntPtr.Size == 4 ? 28 : 32
```

EDIT:  Corrected to be IntPtr.Size, but I like Hans' `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Win32DeviceMgmt.SP_DEVINFO_DATA);` better as there are no magic numbers.  Didn't know that was there.

Comment: Hi there, I realize that the size of IntPtr changes, do you think that this method is best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Why not `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` or `Environment.Is64BitProcess`.

Comment: Unlike `IntPtr.Size`, those will break when we have 128-bit and 256-bit processes.

Comment: @Steven: We will have `Environment.Is128BitOperatingSystem` or even `int Environment.GetOSBits()` at that time.

Comment: Yes, and the code will not know to call these, so it will break. On the other hand, if it calls `IntPtr.Size` and uses the value, it will not break.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an alignment problem.

Try setting the [Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx) property.

*edit*

I looked it up: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SP_DEVINFO_DATA.html

It says:

> On 32bit platforms, all SetupApi
>   structures are 1-Byte packed. On 64bit
>   platforms the SetupApi structures are
>   8-byte packed. IE for 32 bit
>   SP_DEVINFO_DATA.cbSize=28, for 64Bit
>   SP_DEVINFO_DATA.cbSize=(28+4)=32.SP_DEVINFO_DATA.cbSize=(28+4)=32.

Comment: I have tried this property but it didn't work. If you look at the documentation for the SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure you have to specify the cbSize as the size of the structure.